# Add a custom function to a Gradle Project in a convention plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

The Gradle api documentation of [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) states that one can add a dynamic method to a project by

> A property of the project whose value is a closure. The closure is treated as a method and called with the provided parameters. The property is located as described above.

I guess "described above" means that one can use dynamic project properties. These are described in the api documentation as

> A project has 5 property 'scopes', which it searches for properties. You can access these properties by name in your build file, or by calling the project's property(String) method. The scopes are:
>
> ...
>
> - The extra properties of the project. Each project maintains a map of extra properties, which can contain any arbitrary name -> value pair. Once defined, the properties of this scope are readable and writable. See extra properties for more details.

So I thought that I can write a convention plugin, e.g. "sayHello.gradle.kts"

```
// sayhello.gradle.kts
val sayHello : (String) -> Unit = { who ->
    println("Hello $who")
}

ext.set("sayHello", sayHello)
```

and then use the function (or lambda) I added to the project in another `build.gradle.kts`

```
// Some projects build.gradle.kts
plugins {
   id("sayHello")
}

sayHello("René")
```

But I'm getting

```
Script compilation errors:

  Line 7: sayHello("")
          ^ Expression 'sayHello' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

  Line 7: sayHello("")
          ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
              public val TaskContainer.sayHello: TaskProvider<DefaultTask> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
```

I thought that I'm wrong with the Kotlin DSL and read the [*Extra Properties*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:extra_properties) section, but this only shows how values are registered and not closures.

Nevertheless I tried to register a closure similar to the values of the example. So I did:

```
val sayHelloFun : (String) -> Unit = { who ->
    println("Hello $who")
}

val sayHello by extra(sayHelloFun)
```

I got the same error message.

Does anyone know how to add a custom function to a `Project` in a convention plugin using Kotlin DSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Dynamic property access in not available in Kotlin DSL

Unfortunately it's not possible to add functions to the `Project` object in that way from a precompiled script plugin in Kotlin DSL. The [section of the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#properties) that talks about the "five project scopes" anticipates the user is writing a Groovy build script and is not strictly accurate for Kotlin: such access relies on dynamic features of the Groovy language.

To prove this, look at the documentation on using [extra properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:extra_properties). If you compare the Kotlin and Groovy examples, you will see that all the Kotlin extra properties must by accessed using the string name for the property as key, for example by writing `extra["myProperty"]`, whereas Groovy can access them directly.

#### Alternatives

Since Kotlin is statically typed, we instead need a real method the Kotlin compiler can see. There are two alternatives I suggest to do this: Gradle extensions and Kotlin extension functions.

##### Gradle extensions

When you [create an extension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:getting_input_from_the_build), Gradle creates an accessor for that extension. You can use this to create a function in projects applying your plugin, except that you need to call it on the extension rather than `Project` directly:

```
// In plugin script
extensions.create<Greeter>("greeter")

abstract class Greeter {
    fun sayHello() {
        println("G'day mate")
    }
}

// In project build.gradle.kts

greeter.sayHello()
```

##### Kotlin extension functions

This approach is just exploiting a regular [feature of the Kotlin language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html). Such functions must be defined in code that is on the buildscript classpath, so this would not work in a precompiled script plugin (as per your question).

However, such code could be written, for instance, in a regular Kotlin file in the `buildSrc` folder<sup>1</sup>. Then you could simply do:

```
// In buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Greeter.kt

import org.gradle.api.Project

fun Project.sayHello() {
    println("Howdy, partner")
}
    
fun waveGoodbye() { // or a regular function if you don't need the Project object
    println("Ciao, for now")
}

// In project build.gradle.kts

sayHello()
waveGoodbye()
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Such code could also be written inside the compilation of a class-defined plugin.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification. I guess I will use the first approach. The first approach seems to be the better one, since I can provide a custom extension point called `greeter`. This will be more clear for plugin users then extending the project.